# How to add cover page to .pdf in r markdown? And how to customize table of contents?

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, r-markdown

I have nearly finished my first report using r markdown. Now I am stuck with the final 2 issues, that I cannot seem to resolve on my own.

1. I want to add cover pages to the report; before any of the content, and one at the very end. They should not be part of the page-numbering and the table of contents. Ideally, I would just use a PNG or PDF file to fill the entire page at front and back.
2. I need to change the title of the table of contents. As you will see below, I specify in the beginning to include toc, and that the language is da (Danish). However, the title of the toc is in English (Contents). How can I change this text? Maybe language:da is not supported.

Here is a picture of the TOC *(the header I want to change is highlighted)*: 
[image]

The top of my document is as follows:

```
---
title: "TIMSS Rapport"
author: "Anders Christensen et al."
date: "July 16, 2019"
geometry: margin=2cm
fontsize: 12pt
line-height: 1.5
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
classoption: a4paper
language: da
---
```

UPDATE:
I am very new to these things, and was not able to solve the issues with your link. I need more guidance, sorry :).

I looked through your link, and found the argument 'include-before-body'. I have tried adding it without luck:

```
---
title: "TIMSS Rapport, Field trial"
include-before-body: "O:\\ARTS_TIMSS-2019\\elever.jpg"
output:
  pdf_document:
---

and

---
title: "TIMSS Rapport, Field trial"
include-before-body: "O:\\ARTS_TIMSS-2019\\elever.jpg"
output:
  pdf_document:
      include-before-body: "O:\\ARTS_TIMSS-2019\\elever.jpg"
---
```

Do i need to place some sort of \begin and \end for the body, and where should  that be, in order to place the object before the TOC?

As for the change of TOC-header i am still lost. I installed pandoc-templates, but dont see the option in them.

Comment: Use a LaTeX template. See [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#advanced-customization-1).

Comment: As @January comment, and then go ask on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ for specific LaTeX advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default table of contents header by adding toc-title as follows.

**NOTE**: toc-title has no indentation.

```
    output:
      pdf_document:
            toc: yes
            toc_depth:
    toc-title: "your title"
```